# Gradle build failing on CI server, but not in android studio

Tags: android, build, compiler-errors, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up a CI build system with Travis CI. When I build on my laptop with Android studio, everything is peachy-keen.

But when I build on the CI system, it returns this:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':FtcRobotController'.
>
> > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/LibraryPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Now I know next to nothing about android development. (This project is the java equivalent of Arduino, everything in a neat little library for people who don't know android), but this seems really off. Can someone provide be some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of java is on your build server?
As far as I know the:

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Error

Can be resolved by installing the Java 8 JDK

Edit by question poster: just add

```
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

to the .travis.yml file right under the portion of the file where the language in specified.

Comment: thanks. I just looked at the website (travis-ci.com). It appears it defaults to java 7. I need to dig through the docs and see if I can find a way to edit the file and tell it to use 8. I cannot find a way to switch on adroid build. If you have experience in travis, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry I have never used it myself. Good luck finding an answer though.